# How does rysnc work over ssh?

Tags: ssh, rsync

When the rsync program is invoked over ssh what does the interaction between rsync and ssh look like? What feature of ssh is rsync using? I am interested in the interaction between rsync and ssh.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ssh` provides a connected stream from the local system running your `rsync` to another instance running on the remote server. The local `rsync` starts it as part of the `ssh` connection process - it is *not* the same instance of `rsync` that might be running as a daemon on that remote server.

---

What is an *ssh stream*?

An *ssh stream* is what you use when you `ssh` to a remote system. You might prefer to call it an *ssh session*. That's fine. As an example, `ssh snow@grumpy.example.net` would connect you to that remote system and give you an interactive session. Anything you typed locally would be received and actioned remotely, and anything generated remotely would be presented to you locally.

Similarly, `ssh -t snow@doc.example.net vi /etc/hosts` would set up a connection to run `vi /etc/hosts` on the remote system as if you were using it locally. (The `-t` flag tells `ssh` to ensure that the remote command, `vi`, is run on a pseudo-terminal; otherwise it would skip that layer of complexity.)

Now, for `rsync`, the connection is set up by the local instance with something like `ssh snow@bashful.example.net rsync --server -nlogDtpre.iLsf {local_path} {remote_path}`. This allows the local `rsync` to talk with the remote `rsync` over a connection just like you would use to access that same remote server. The remote instance of `rsync` knows it's a server because of the flags it has been provided when started by the local instance.

You can see how `rsync` has been called remotely by running something like `ssh snow@dopey.example.net 'ps -ef | grep [r]sync'` while the `rsync` is in progress.

Why not just have `rsync` talk directly without `ssh`?

The advantage of using `ssh` is twofold

1. It is a well known protocol and the mechanisms for authentication and logging in to a remote system are well understood (by those who need to understand it) and trusted
2. It provides a secure and encrypted channel over which any sensitive data can be safely passed. Without this layer `rsync` would either have to implement its own encryption or ignore the issue. Both are hazardous in today's Internet connected world.