# rsync bash script "unable to stat"

Tags: shell-script, ssh, rsync

I am writing a bash script to rsync from one machine to another machine over ssh on LAN. It is giving me a link_stat error, and referencing a directory from which the source I am totally unsure of.

What is this error suggesting, and where is this path coming from in script??

the location of the Backup folder is /home/user/rsynctest/

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -av ssh ../Backup/ 192.168.100.120:/media/storage1/Backup
```

the error...

```
    sending incremental file list
    rsync: link_stat "/home/user/rsynctest/Backup/ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)

    sent 270 bytes  received 16 bytes  572.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 23  speedup is 0.08
    rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Comment: indications are that `/home/user/rsynctest/Backup/ssh` is a broken symlink; is that so?

Comment: How does on determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to tell `rsync` to use ssh.  It will use it by default when given a remote path.  The "ssh" on your command line is interpreted as just another filepath to be copied.  Since the rsync process can't find a file by that name, it complains (and then goes on and copies the next path given).

So change

```
rsync -av ssh ../Backup/ 192.168.100.120:/media/storage1/Backup
```

to

```
rsync -av ../Backup/ 192.168.100.120:/media/storage1/Backup
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following,

```
rsync -av ../Backup/ -e ssh 192.168.100.120:/media/storage1/Backup
```

OR

```
rsync -ave ssh ../Backup/ 192.168.100.120:/media/storage1/Backup
```

**Reason for not working:**

When you are going to use `ssh` to transfer your files then you have to use the `-e` flag. From manpage,

> -e, --rsh=COMMAND    specify the remote shell to use

Here by using `-e ssh` you are specifying that you want to connect to the remote shell via `ssh stream`. If you want to know more how `ssh` works in rsync please check the following URL,

[How does rysnc work over ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197686/171196)

Comment: Thanks. Where would an exclude flag go in that mix?

Comment: I didn't change your command, just added `-e ssh`. So whatever you trying to do just add that part and it will work nicely.